# How do I remove extra XML tags?

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull out the text from an XML file. I got most of the contents out but some tags still remain.

I used BeautifulSoup to remove the tags, but I still have the span tag. Why?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


f = open(directory+files[4],"r")
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, features="lxml")

for content in soup.findAll([re.compile('us-gaap:.*'), 'span','table','p']):
    print(content.text)
```

[image: Command Line Output]

Comment: Generally, it's not a good idea to work with regex on html files and definitely not with edgar filings (which is what it seems you have).

Comment: What do you recommend I do? I trying to figure the best way to pull the data out of the edgar filings